# Can someone help me with this uibutton error?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I know that is minor error but I stick here till 1 hour.please recommend me fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't force unwrap the value.
and put that line of code before present view controller code.
This will solve your issue.